# SpringBoot CRUD Repository fail to Autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with SpringBoot and JPA. I'm getting an error with an `@Autowired` that could not be completed.

This is my main class:

```
package com;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.repository")
public class InitBatch implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Batch batch;

    @Autowired
    private CareDao careDAO;


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        careDAO.setMessageSource(messageSource());      
        batch.processFiles();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(InitBatch.class, args).close();
        System.out.println("Finish");
    }


    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("file:/config/instances");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(100);
        return messageSource;
    }   
}
```

This my class that fails:

```
package com.logger.impl;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.repository"})

@Component
public class RequestLoggerImpl implements RequestLogger {

    @Autowired
    private RequestLogDao requestLogDao;

}
```

This is the `RequestLogDao` class:

```
package com.repository;
public interface RequestLogDao extends CrudRepository<RequestLog, Integer> {

}
```

This is the error message:

> Error creating bean with name 'requestLoggerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
>
> Could not autowire field: private com.repository.RequestLogDao com.logger.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.requestLogDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.repository.RequestLogDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I just can't find out why it can't autowire. I have tried adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` in my main class, but this did not work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To start, you shouldn't have your `RequestLoggerImpl` annotated as `@Configuration`--it's a service bean, not a configuration class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your request logger, remove the configuration and component scan first

```
package com.logger.impl;

@Component
public class RequestLoggerImpl implements RequestLogger {

    @Autowired
    private RequestLogDao requestLogDao;

}
```

Since you've placed a @Configuration, i assume you will need a config class so you can create one like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.repository"}
public class MyConfiguration {
    // possibly your Bean declarations here
    // like dataSource, transactionManager etc.. related to your jpa repo
    // as needed
}
```

Take note of your base package here; as it will be used for:

```
package com.repository;

@Repository
public interface RequestLogDao extends CrudRepository<RequestLog, Integer> {
    // ...
}
```

Finally in your Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication // scan base packages for autowiring as needed
public class InitBatch implements CommandLineRunner {
    // ...
}
```

Lastly check your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Remove both

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.repository"})
```

from RequestLoggerImpl

And remove `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.repository")` from main class. And move main class to directly under `com` package

And I assume, you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency added

Answer (score -3):

Do you have a concrete class that implements `RequestLogDao`?  I don't see one.

You need to have one (a Java class), and you need to make an instance of it available in the application context.

Comment: He is using Spring Data JPA, so he doesn't need implementation.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code included in his question that would cause a live object implementing `RequestLogDao` to be present in the app context.